# remove a line from the beginning of a buffer

Tags: c

I have a network programming c code that can retrieve a HTTP page, the thing is I want to remove GET response header that come with the actual data of the page, I know that I have to look for the first "\r\n\r\n" but all the thing that I've tried so far didn't work !
so how can I strip these response header line from the beginning of the buffer??

Comment: Then its probably a good idea to show the code you wrote that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the GET response header is at the beggining of the buffer, you may try to find the first occurence of "\r\n\r\n" using a function like strstr:

```
char *p = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
```

and then return p+4, because p will point to the first \r. p+4 will point to whatever is after the "\r\n\r\n". To return it from a function, just return p+4.

Comment: thank you so much that was helpful, the code run correctly now